Apache on Xampp don"t run
I am using XAMPPS to host PHP files from my machine. I have recently installed XAMPPs but I am unable to start Apache.
This is the situation.
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this entire log window on the forums
i have already change the servername and port in httpd.conf
How can i fix it?

This is impressive. Have you read what is writte in the error message you cite? "copy and post this entire log window on the forums" ...
